# Iterating function in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new in python and I'm finding problems in understanding how to work with lists and dictionaries. In particular, I cannot solve this problem:

Given the following dictionary:

```
A=[{'t':1, 'X':10, 'Y': 15},
   {'t':4, 'X':2500, 'Y': 3000},
   {'t':1, 'X':20, 'Y': 10},
   {'t':3, 'X':0.10, 'Y': 0.40},
   {'t':2, 'X':400, 'Y': 400},
   {'t':3, 'X':0.20, 'Y': 0.10},
]
```

I have to write a code that create a new dictionary such that, for every `t`, `X` and `Y` are summed. Then each `t` must appear only once (chronologically) and those sums which belongs to same `t` must all be summed together. The output should be something like this:

```
B=[{'t':1, 'SUM':55},
   {'t':2, 'SUM':800},
   {'t':3, 'SUM':0.80},
   {'t':4, 'SUM':5500},
]
```

Please, someone can help me?

Comment: So start with a dictionary, to track the sums, with `t` as the key. Then after you collected the sums, produce your separate dictionaries.

Comment: @Dhy12 you should accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> A=[{'t':1, 'X':10, 'Y': 15},
...    {'t':4, 'X':2500, 'Y': 3000},
...    {'t':1, 'X':20, 'Y': 10},
...    {'t':3, 'X':0.10, 'Y': 0.40},
...    {'t':2, 'X':400, 'Y': 400},
...    {'t':3, 'X':0.20, 'Y': 0.10},
... ]
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for d in A:
...     my_dict.update({d['t']: my_dict.pop(d['t'],0) + d['Y'] + d['X']})
... 
>>> my_dict
{1: 55, 2: 800, 3: 0.8, 4: 5500}
>>> my_list=[]
>>> for k in sorted(my_dict.keys()):
...     my_list.append({"t":k,"SUM":my_dict[k]})
... 
>>> my_list
[{'SUM': 55, 't': 1}, {'SUM': 800, 't': 2}, {'SUM': 0.8, 't': 3}, {'SUM': 5500, 't': 4}]
>>>
```

Comment: I don't think I'd use either `update` or `pop` in that first loop. The equivalent line `my_dict[d['t']] = my_dict.get(d['t'], 0) + d['Y'] + d['X']` seems much nicer. Other than that quibble, this is definitely the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
A=[{'t':1, 'X':10, 'Y': 15},
   {'t':4, 'X':2500, 'Y': 3000},
   {'t':1, 'X':20, 'Y': 10},
   {'t':3, 'X':0.10, 'Y': 0.40},
   {'t':2, 'X':400, 'Y': 400},
   {'t':3, 'X':0.20, 'Y': 0.10},
]

output_dict = {}
for item in A:
    if item['t'] in output_dict:
        output_dict[item['t']] +=  item['X'] + item['Y']
    else:
        output_dict[item['t']] =  item['X'] + item['Y']

output_list = []
for key in sorted(output_dict.keys()):
    output_list.append({"t":key, "SUM":output_dict[key]})

for item in output_list:
    print(item)
```

It outputs:

```
{'t': 1, 'SUM': 55}
{'t': 2, 'SUM': 800}
{'t': 3, 'SUM': 0.8}
{'t': 4, 'SUM': 5500}
```